# Can't save data using ActiveRecord.update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm following railstutorial and I stuck on Chapter 7 (near figure 7.8)

I can't update attributes using update_attributes method of ActiveRecord class

The exact steps I'm taking and error it gives me:

```
    1.9.3p392 :026 > user = User.first
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, name: "John Denisov", email: "denisov@gmail.com", created_at: "2013-06-17 19:49:49", updated_at: "2013-06-17 19:49:49", password_digest: "$2a$10$eU2XgCqdKP9iBf7.2J4rKuBYmyicO42uahlm3DWwT7Xe..."> 
1.9.3p392 :027 > user.update_attributes(name: "Example User", email: "example@railstutorial.org", password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('example@railstutorial.org') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
 => false
```

Why would it give me User Exists error? It's kinda obvious, I'm trying to update, not create
the database entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a uniqueness validation on email and the email `example@railstutorial.org` already exists on the database for a different user.

Try with a different email address.

Comment: thanks, deleted the entry with the same email using delete(id) method.I just forgot about email uniqueness validation.